# Method onReceive of BroadcastReceiver runs twice

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, internet-connection

I'm trying to detect internet connection and disconnection by broadcast receiver.

My broadcast receiver:

```
public class InternetConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(isOnline(context))
        {
            Log.e("internet", "connected");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("internet", "disconnected");
        }
    }

    public boolean isOnline(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());

    }
}
```

In the manifest:

```
<receiver
      android:name=".receivers.InternetConnectivityReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true">

      <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
      </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

I don't understand when I connect or disconnect internet why method onReceive runs twice?

Can anyone help me?

**Update**

This is my logcat output:

```
01-01 17:26:06.640 17883-17883/ir.ac.um.androidhistory E/internet: connected
01-01 17:26:26.270 17883-17883/ir.ac.um.androidhistory E/internet: connected
01-01 17:27:18.990 17883-17883/ir.ac.um.androidhistory E/internet: disconnected
01-01 17:27:37.910 17883-17883/ir.ac.um.androidhistory E/internet: disconnected
01-01 17:27:59.800 17883-17883/ir.ac.um.androidhistory E/internet: connected
01-01 17:28:08.120 17883-17883/ir.ac.um.androidhistory E/internet: connected
```

Comment: Check your code again, may be your calling `BroadcastReceiver` twice.

Comment: What do you mean from 'calling'? I don't call anything. I have just added this receiver into the manifest.

Comment: Provide your logcat.